# EFSを解除しながらファイルコピーする方法

Tags: windows

NTFSドライブ上でEFS(Encrypted File System)暗号化されたファイルを、外付けHDDなどにコピーすると**同時に**EFSを解除する方法を教えてください。（コピー先もNTFSフォーマットを想定しています）

GUI操作でファイルコピー完了後にEFS解除することもできますが、対象ファイルが巨大な場合には相当な処理時間がかかってしまいます。

Microsoft KBでは[[HOWTO] サーバーにファイルをコピーする際に暗号化されないようにする方法](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302093/ja)が公開されていますが、これはコピー先のファイルサーバ設定のようです。

Comment: [このSuperUserでの同じ質問の回答によると](http://superuser.com/questions/188119/how-to-remove-encrypted-flag-when-copying-a-file-from-a-hdd-to-a-usb-drive/781914#781914)、RichCopyはこの場合使えます。　http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fire File Copy](http://www.k3.dion.ne.jp/~kitt/pc/sw/ffc/)など、Explorer経由でない方法でコピーを行うツールを使ってみてはどうでしょうか(XP HomeでHDD→別HDDで試したところ解除されていました)。

Answer (score 0):

外付けハードディスクであれば、フォーマットをNTFSではなくFAT32やらexFATにすれば暗号化できないため解除された状態でコピーされるのではないかと思います。

Comment: 質問文では明記していませんでしたが、外部HDDもNTFSフォーマットを使っていました。（巨大ファイルを扱いたいため）